# When using SQL Server UNION ALL, can I merge columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, union-all

I have two tables in SQL Server.

- Table 1: `JBIN` : A List of ALL invoices.
- Table 2: `ARTH` : List of ALL invoices that are approved.

I have created a query which displays information on the number of days that an invoice is overdue by.

The results table looks like this:

```
+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+------+
|     OverdueRange      | OverdueCount | Total Amount | INVO |
+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+------+
| Due in 0-7 days       |            1 | 180215.61    |   -1 |
| Due in 31-45 days     |            1 | 153356.10    |  -32 |
| Overdue by 46+ days   |            1 | 125167.34    |   47 |
| Due in 0-7 days       |           25 | 2708613.25   |   -1 |
| Due in 31-45 days     |            3 | 62312.51     |  -32 |
| Overdue by 15-30 days |           12 | 295140.15    |   16 |
| Overdue by 1-7 days   |            1 | 111070.25    |    2 |
| Overdue by 31-45 days |            1 | 2150.50      |   32 |
| Overdue by 46+ days   |            8 | 546907.75    |   47 |
| Overdue by 8-14 days  |            1 | 156985.68    |    9 |
+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+------+
```

In this query, I have a `UNION ALL` statement.

The first three rows of the table is from `JBIN` whereas the rest are from `ARTH`.

Is it possible, when using `UNION ALL` to combine the data. For example, instead of having two rows called "Due in 0-7 days, I have ONE single row which SUMS the OverdueCount and Total Amount fields.

E.G.

Instead of this:

```
+-----------------+--------------+--------------+------+
|  OverdueRange   | OverdueCount | Total Amount | INVO |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------+------+
| Due in 0-7 days |            1 | 180215.61    |   -1 |
| Due in 0-7 days |           25 | 2708613.25   |   -1 |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------+------+
```

I want this:

```
+-----------------+--------------+--------------+------+
|  OverdueRange   | OverdueCount | Total Amount | INVO |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------+------+
| Due in 0-7 days |           26 | 2888828.86   |   -1 |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------+------+
```

FYI:

This is my query:

```
WITH Temp ([InvDescription], [InvoiceAmount], [OverdueBy], [DatePaid])
AS 
(select InvDescription, InvTotal as InvoiceAmount, (DATEDIFF(day,DueDate,GETDATE())) as OverdueBy, NULL as DatePaid from JBIN
Where InvStatus <> 'I' and JBCo = 1 and InvTotal > 0 

),
Temp2 ([InvDescription], [InvoiceAmount], [OverdueBy], [DatePaid])
AS 
(select Description, SUM(Invoiced) as InvoiceAmount, (DATEDIFF(day,DueDate,GETDATE())) as OverdueBy, PayFullDate as DatePaid from ARTH
Where ARCo = 1 and Invoiced > 0 
Group By Description, DueDate, PayFullDate, Invoice
)
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN OverdueBy >= 46 THEN 'Overdue by 46+ days' 
        WHEN OverdueBy >= 31 and OverdueBy <= 45 THEN 'Overdue by 31-45 days'
        WHEN OverdueBy >= 15 and OverdueBy <= 30 THEN 'Overdue by 15-30 days'
        WHEN OverdueBy >= 8 and OverdueBy <= 14 THEN 'Overdue by 8-14 days'
        WHEN OverdueBy >= 1 and OverdueBy <= 7 THEN 'Overdue by 1-7 days'
        WHEN OverdueBy <= 0 and OverdueBy >= -7 THEN 'Due in 0-7 days'
        WHEN OverdueBy <= -8 and OverdueBy >= -14 THEN 'Due in 8-14 days'
        WHEN OverdueBy <= -15 and OverdueBy >= -30 THEN 'Due in 15-30 days'
        WHEN OverdueBy <= -31 and OverdueBy >= -45 THEN 'Due in 31-45 days'
        WHEN OverdueBy <= -46 THEN 'Due in 46+ days'
        ELSE 'Less than that' 
   END AS OverdueRange,
   Count(*) as OverdueCount,
   Sum(Temp.InvoiceAmount) as [Total Amount], 
   CASE WHEN OverdueBy >= 46 THEN '47' 
        WHEN OverdueBy >= 31 and OverdueBy <= 45 THEN '32'
        WHEN OverdueBy >= 15 and OverdueBy <= 30 THEN '16'
        WHEN OverdueBy >= 8 and OverdueBy <= 14 THEN '9'
        WHEN OverdueBy >= 1 and OverdueBy <= 7 THEN '2'
        WHEN OverdueBy <= 0 and OverdueBy >= -7 THEN '-1'
        WHEN OverdueBy <= -8 and OverdueBy >= -14 THEN '-9'
        WHEN OverdueBy <= -15 and OverdueBy >= -30 THEN '-16'
        WHEN OverdueBy <= -31 and OverdueBy >= -45 THEN '-32'
        WHEN OverdueBy <= -46 THEN '-47'
        ELSE 'ERROR' 
   END AS [INVO]
From Temp
group by CASE WHEN OverdueBy >= 46 THEN 'Overdue by 46+ days' 
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 31 and OverdueBy <= 45 THEN 'Overdue by 31-45 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 15 and OverdueBy <= 30 THEN 'Overdue by 15-30 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 8 and OverdueBy <= 14 THEN 'Overdue by 8-14 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 1 and OverdueBy <= 7 THEN 'Overdue by 1-7 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= 0 and OverdueBy >= -7 THEN 'Due in 0-7 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -8 and OverdueBy >= -14 THEN 'Due in 8-14 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -15 and OverdueBy >= -30 THEN 'Due in 15-30 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -31 and OverdueBy >= -45 THEN 'Due in 31-45 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -46 THEN 'Due in 46+ days'

ELSE 'Less than that' END,
CASE WHEN OverdueBy >= 46 THEN '47' 
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 31 and OverdueBy <= 45 THEN '32'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 15 and OverdueBy <= 30 THEN '16'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 8 and OverdueBy <= 14 THEN '9'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 1 and OverdueBy <= 7 THEN '2'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= 0 and OverdueBy >= -7 THEN '-1'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -8 and OverdueBy >= -14 THEN '-9'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -15 and OverdueBy >= -30 THEN '-16'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -31 and OverdueBy >= -45 THEN '-32'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -46 THEN '-47'
ELSE 'ERROR' END
UNION ALL 

SELECT CASE WHEN OverdueBy >= 46 THEN 'Overdue by 46+ days' 
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 31 and OverdueBy <= 45 THEN 'Overdue by 31-45 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 15 and OverdueBy <= 30 THEN 'Overdue by 15-30 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 8 and OverdueBy <= 14 THEN 'Overdue by 8-14 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 1 and OverdueBy <= 7 THEN 'Overdue by 1-7 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= 0 and OverdueBy >= -7 THEN 'Due in 0-7 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -8 and OverdueBy >= -14 THEN 'Due in 8-14 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -15 and OverdueBy >= -30 THEN 'Due in 15-30 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -31 and OverdueBy >= -45 THEN 'Due in 31-45 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -46 THEN 'Due in 46+ days'
ELSE 'Less than that' END AS OverdueRange,
Count(*) as OverdueCount,
Sum(Temp2.InvoiceAmount) as [Total Amount], 
CASE WHEN OverdueBy >= 46 THEN '47' 
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 31 and OverdueBy <= 45 THEN '32'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 15 and OverdueBy <= 30 THEN '16'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 8 and OverdueBy <= 14 THEN '9'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 1 and OverdueBy <= 7 THEN '2'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= 0 and OverdueBy >= -7 THEN '-1'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -8 and OverdueBy >= -14 THEN '-9'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -15 and OverdueBy >= -30 THEN '-16'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -31 and OverdueBy >= -45 THEN '-32'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -46 THEN '-47'
ELSE 'ERROR' END AS [INVO]
From Temp2
Where Temp2.DatePaid is null

group by CASE WHEN OverdueBy >= 46 THEN 'Overdue by 46+ days' 
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 31 and OverdueBy <= 45 THEN 'Overdue by 31-45 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 15 and OverdueBy <= 30 THEN 'Overdue by 15-30 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 8 and OverdueBy <= 14 THEN 'Overdue by 8-14 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 1 and OverdueBy <= 7 THEN 'Overdue by 1-7 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= 0 and OverdueBy >= -7 THEN 'Due in 0-7 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -8 and OverdueBy >= -14 THEN 'Due in 8-14 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -15 and OverdueBy >= -30 THEN 'Due in 15-30 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -31 and OverdueBy >= -45 THEN 'Due in 31-45 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -46 THEN 'Due in 46+ days'

ELSE 'Less than that' END,
CASE WHEN OverdueBy >= 46 THEN '47' 
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 31 and OverdueBy <= 45 THEN '32'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 15 and OverdueBy <= 30 THEN '16'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 8 and OverdueBy <= 14 THEN '9'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 1 and OverdueBy <= 7 THEN '2'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= 0 and OverdueBy >= -7 THEN '-1'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -8 and OverdueBy >= -14 THEN '-9'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -15 and OverdueBy >= -30 THEN '-16'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -31 and OverdueBy >= -45 THEN '-32'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -46 THEN '-47'
ELSE 'ERROR' END
```

Comment: why don't you add one more CTE, and assign overdue (... Overdue by 31-45 days ...) values as a new column in CTE query

Comment: I believe your question is not how to merge columns but how to merge rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a derived table from your union all query.  Something like this:

```
select somefields, sum(something) thesum
from (
union all query goes here
) derivedTable
group by somefields
```

Comment: Any chance you can be more specific? I tried this, but I think I am doing it all wrong.

Comment: The queries in your question are very convoluted, probably more so than necessary.  Start with something simple and build it up.